# PHPUnit Testing Error : The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: phpunit

I have installed PHPUnit via Pear.

While I try testing via PHPUnit,even after giving the test file path it shows error: 
The system cannot find the path specified.

I have tried Sample code in :
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html?print=yes#installing-phpunit

```
<?php
class Calculator
{
    /**
     * @assert (0, 0) == 0
     * @assert (0, 1) == 1
     * @assert (1, 0) == 1
     * @assert (1, 1) == 2
     * @assert (1, 2) == 4
     */
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your source file is called, but there are not any tests written in for the class.  You used the generator, which has created the @asserts.  Now, you need to generate the test class to use those.  The [PHPUnit Manual Skeleton Generator](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/skeleton-generator.html) is then needed to run to produce the actual tests.

With your code, you have the sample @assert annotations for what should be simple to generate test cases.  Therefore, you need to generate the test cases.

```
phpunit-skelgen --test Calculator
```

or  for Namespaces (where Project is the name space)

```
phpunit-skelgen --test -- "project\Calculator" Calculator.php
```

Then you can see tests generated

```
/**
 * Generated from @assert (0, 0) == 0.
 */
public function testAdd() {
    $o = new Calculator;
    $this->assertEquals(0, $o->add(0, 0));
}
```

Finally, you can execute your tests:

```
 phpunit --bootstrap Calculator.php --verbose CalculatorTest
```